# Enumeration management with zend framework (ZF)?

Tags: php, zend-framework, enumeration, preferences

Is there any existing project or incubator to manage user administratable lists of options? We have several 100 lists (most populate dropdowns in our application), many are quite short < 50 items, several with a few hundred items and a handful with thousands (<30,000) entries.

What we are looking for is a database based structure and UI that lets a user make edits to entries.

We took a look at Xyster enum but is lacks any UI and would need work to make it DB capable.

A user preferences "module" might meet many of our needs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that Zend Framework has what you are looking for. You might be better off looking at some full-stack frameworks that will generate Rails-like scaffold admin pages automatically based on model/table definitions. Try looking at [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) or [QCodo](http://qcodo.com/) in PHP or [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/), [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) if you are not bothered about using PHP. Don't get me wrong, Zend Framework can do what you want but it will require a fair bit of custom code.